# Performance difference between one join or 2 joins and 1 union all

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join

I'm analyzing the join operator performance in PostgreSQL and found this:

```
Merge Full Join  (cost=26144.09..27373.25 rows=176921 width=442) (actual time=127.207..218.997 rows=177706 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (pet.player_id = p.id)
  ->  Sort  (cost=26028.80..26471.11 rows=176921 width=57) (actual time=126.850..166.591 rows=176941 loops=1)
        Sort Key: pet.player_id
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13040kB
```

So before joining itself we perform sorting first. The sorting algorithms in its best has *O*(*n* log *n*) complexity, so I expected 2 joins and 1 union to work fast on large amount of data. In fact it works even slower that 1 join. I conducted several experiments and got the following stats in average:

> one join (two tables with 250k rows):  17233sec
>   2 joins and 1 union (the same tables):  20422sec

A join algorithm used in the experiments was sort-merge join. `Set enable_mergejoin To true`.

Why is 2 joins and 1 union slower in this case?

Comment: Downvoter, it's not an opinion-based. It's a question about performance.

Comment: Hard to say whitout looking at an explai result of the second query. Please add the explain analyze reslult of the query with union, then we will be able to compare them.

Comment: I agree, far from opinion-based, but would require more information, preferably the queries, table structures with data amounts and both results for `ANALYZE`s to be able to provide any insights. Edited the title a bit to look less like a generic opinion question.

Comment: It is hard to tell without the table definitions and the actual queries. I would expect 2*join+union to be more than twice as expensive as 1*join. The fact that is is only 15% more expensive could be caused by cache-warming.